# How to understand disk usage in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, storage

I installed Windows 10 Pro on my newly bought 240 GB SSD.

then i partitioned it into 3;
~80 GB (as C:), ~20 GB (as D:), ~100 GB (as linux)

but when I checked on Disk Storage in Windows 10, it said 129 GB used of 183 GB C:\ drive.

[image: screenshot of drive partitions]

where's that come from? weren't it shoud be only 80 GB of C:\ ?
and i'm sure the usage was less than that, since it's newly install.
anyone kindly explain it to me?

thank you.

Comment: 80 GB is a bit small for Windows 10. You need about 30 GB spare space for a feature update. I would have allocated 50 GB for Linux (all my Linux machines fit in this space), and allocated all the remaining space for Windows 10.

Comment: We would rely onto the Data reported by the _Disk Management_ Software Utility, @snydez. There must be a Software Fault inside the _Storage_ Pane.

Comment: @John depends on what you install inside Windows. I've once used Windows 10 on a 32GB SSD without problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows wants to represent the usage of the whole physical disk in some manner, so it also counts all unrecognized partitions as '100% used' when showing the usage of the OS volume.

(Or, in other words, that's the entire physical disk that the C: volume is on, *minus* all other Windows-compatible partitions that get their own space indications. For example, volume D: gets its own info section, but the Linux partition clearly doesn't – so its size must be accounted *somewhere*.)

It's certainly a bit misleading to mix up the whole disk with the system partition, but the general idea is not *entirely* wrong – your 5th partition contains 100 GB of non-Windows data, so as far as Windows is concerned, that's 100 GB of physical disk space that's been taken away from the user.

Comment: Ah i see, 
so for trial, i will try to resize the linux partition to see whether the total usage changes too.
thanks